# Out of index error usando forall sum en minizinc

Tags: array, math

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
include "alldifferent.mzn";
include "par1.dzn"; %incluimos los parametros del archivo

%PARAMETROS
par int: NumServidores;
par int: NumClientes;

array[1..NumServidores] of var int: CapacidadServidores;
array[1..NumClientes] of var int: DemandaClientes;
array[1..NumClientes] of var int: SeguridadClientes;

%matriz tal que las filas son los servidores y las columnas los clientes
%almacenará cuantas unidades de computo del cliente j almacenara el servidor i
array [1..NumServidores, 1..NumClientes] of var int: Solucion;

%RESTRICCIONES

%compruebo que ningun servidor exceda su capacidad
constraint forall(servidor in 1..NumServidores) (sum(cliente in 1..NumClientes) (Solucion[servidor, cliente]) <= CapacidadServidores[servidor]); 
%compruebo que ningun cliente de mas carga de la que necesita dar.
constraint forall(cliente in 1..NumClientes) (sum(servidor in 1..NumServidores) (Solucion[servidor, cliente]) <= DemandaClientes[cliente]);
%compruebo que ningun servidor almacene demás para cada cliente segun la seguridad
constraint forall(cliente in 1..NumClientes, servidor in 1..NumServidores) (Solucion[cliente, servidor] <= SeguridadClientes[cliente]);


% Solucionar el modelo
solve satisfy;

% Mostrar la solución
output ["Matriz solucion:\n", show(Solucion), "\n"];
```

Con el que intento resolver un problema de asignacion de carga computacional de 6 clientes entre 8 servidores, pero me da el siguiente error en la matriz solucion:

```
model1:24.12-134
  in call 'forall'
  in array comprehension expression
    with cliente = 1
    with servidor = 7
  in binary '<=' operator expression
  in array access
Warning: undefined result becomes false in Boolean context
  (array access out of bounds, dimension 2 of array has index set 1..6, but given index is 7)
model1:24.12-134
  in call 'forall'
  in array comprehension expression
    with cliente = 1
    with servidor = 7
  in binary '<=' operator expression
  in array access
Warning: model inconsistency detected
=====UNSATISFIABLE=====
Finished in 82msec.
```

He probado a cambiar el orden de los indices en los array solucion tanto en su declaracion como en su uso, pero no he conseguido que funione.